# Multiple nested levels query return only one path

Tags: elasticsearch, elastic-stack, elasticsearch-dsl

In the example given,

Here is the index....

```
 PUT /drivers/_doc/1
{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "McQueen",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}

PUT /drivers/_doc/2?refresh
{
  "driver" : {
        "last_name" : "Hudson",
        "vehicle" : [
            {
                "make" : "Mifune",
                "model" : "Mach Five"
            },
            {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

And I query like this:

```
GET /drivers/_search
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver",
      "query": {
        "nested": {
          "path": "driver.vehicle",
          "query": {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                { "match": { "driver.vehicle.make": "Powell Motors" } },
                { "match": { "driver.vehicle.model": "Canyonero" } }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

And get this as result:

```
{
  "took" : 5,
  "timed_out" : false,
  "_shards" : {
    "total" : 1,
    "successful" : 1,
    "skipped" : 0,
    "failed" : 0
  },
  "hits" : {
    "total" : {
      "value" : 1,
      "relation" : "eq"
    },
    "max_score" : 3.7349272,
    "hits" : [
      {
        "_index" : "drivers",
        "_type" : "_doc",
        "_id" : "1",
        "_score" : 3.7349272,
        "_source" : {
          "driver" : {
            "last_name" : "McQueen",
            "vehicle" : [
              {
                "make" : "Powell Motors",
                "model" : "Canyonero"
              },
              {
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However, as one can see, it contains the other child also, which is :

```
{
                "make" : "Miller-Meteor",
                "model" : "Ecto-1"
              }
```

which I don't want. Can anybody please help here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `inner_hits` along with the nested query, to get only the matching nested object in the result. Modify your search query as

```
{
  "query": {
    "nested": {
      "path": "driver.vehicle",
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "must": [
            {
              "match": {
                "driver.vehicle.make": "Powell Motors"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "driver.vehicle.model": "Canyonero"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "inner_hits":{}
    }
  }
}
```

Search Result will be

```
"hits": [
      {
        "_index": "68082033",
        "_type": "_doc",
        "_id": "1",
        "_score": 3.7349272,
        "_source": {
          "driver": {
            "last_name": "McQueen",
            "vehicle": [
              {
                "make": "Powell Motors",
                "model": "Canyonero"
              },
              {
                "make": "Miller-Meteor",
                "model": "Ecto-1"
              }
            ]
          }
        },
        "inner_hits": {
          "driver.vehicle": {
            "hits": {
              "total": {
                "value": 1,
                "relation": "eq"
              },
              "max_score": 3.7349272,
              "hits": [
                {
                  "_index": "68082033",
                  "_type": "_doc",
                  "_id": "1",
                  "_nested": {
                    "field": "driver.vehicle",
                    "offset": 0
                  },
                  "_score": 3.7349272,
                  "_source": {
                    "model": "Canyonero",         // note this
                    "make": "Powell Motors"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        }
      }
    ]
```